# cdf of hypergeometric related to Appell Series

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I'm looking at a function (pdf) of the form

$f_X(x)=K \cdot \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{(1+dx)^c}$ for $0<x<1$, $a,b>0$, $d>-1$
Also, K is the constant which makes this integral evaluate to 1 over $0<x<1$
Using the integral representation of the hypergeometric function, we get that

$\frac{1}{K}= B(a,b) \cdot _2F_1(c,a;a+b;-d)$

How do I find the cdf of such a function?

The cdf is supposed to be $F_X(x)= K \int_{0}^{x} \cdot \frac{y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1}dy}{(1+dx)^c}= \frac{Kx^a}{a} \cdot F_1(a,c,1-b,a+1;-dx,x)  $$ where $F_1$ is the Appell function. I'm not sure why that is or how to show it.

Comment: Go to the Appell Series Wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series) and look at the Integral Representations section.

Comment: ok but when I plug in the corrrsponding values I get a* $\int_{0}^{1} t^{a-1}(1+dxt)^{-c}(1-xt)^{b-1}dt$ what am I missing? also we're trying to integrate up to x here, not 1

Comment: You're not substituting correctly.  In the Wiki equation you want $y$ set to 0, $x$ set to $d$, $t$ set to $x$, $c-a-1$ set to $b-1$, etc.

Comment: You can also use binomial theorem twice and use $F_1$’s series expansion.

Comment: sorry Jim I don't see why you're choosing those numbers. I've just heard of this series so bear with me

Comment: Tyma, could expand more on your comment